# Get word from one table and filter out rows containing that word from other table

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables,

```
table1

    select * from table1,

    word

    ilo
    word1
    go

    Table2,

    select * from table2

        ID         column1          column2         column3
        1           pilot            pandas           sql
        2            USA              UK              India
        3            SQL             python       word1word2word3
        4           came              gone            went
```

I want to take words from table1 and filter out rows in table2 whenever those words occur in any of the three columns out of column1, column2 and column3. My output here should be,

```
ID         column1          column2         column3
2            USA              UK              India
```

because, pilot, word1word2word3 and gone contains words from the first table.

I tried the following,

```
select ID, column1, column2, column3,  case when instr(column1, word) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as ignore from table2 full outer join table1 on 1=1 where ignore = 0
```

I have written the logic only for one column.

This seems to work. But since I am giving 1=1 here, all the entries are getting duplicated. I am getting the following as output,

```
ID         column1          column2         column3     ignore
2            USA              UK              India       0
2            USA              UK              India       0
```

Can anybody help me in solving this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you figure out which RDBMS you're using?

Comment: @Strawberry actually it is hive table. But since it is sql, I tagged all the databases.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a group by clause to collapse the duplicates?  I assume since you have an ID that won't cause problems.

Comment: @Matt One ID would be having several entries. Cant use group by

Comment: Why are there 3 'columns' as opposed to 1, or 4, say?

Comment: @Strawberry I am not getting your question?

Answer (score 0):

When you say `any of the three columns` you can concat three columns.

If is is SQL Server, use this code

First join two tables like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM table2
     INNER JOIN table1 ON CHARINDEX(table1.word, (column1 + column2 + column3)) > 0
```

This will show the rows that exists in table2, then you can use this code to filter out.

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ID NOT IN 
    ( SELECT ID FROM table2
         INNER JOIN table1 ON CHARINDEX(table1.word, (column1 + column2 + column3)) > 0 )
```

If it is not SQL Server replace `CharIndex` with `instr` or any other find function.

Comment: I tried instr instead of charindex, but I am getting both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0'

Comment: SELECT ID FROM table2
     INNER JOIN table1 ON CHARINDEX(table1.word, column1) > 0

Comment: This is the query I used

Comment: for instr you should replace params, write instr((column1 + column2 + column3), table1.word) > 0

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports correlated subqueries for `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t2.col1 like '%' || t1.word || '%' or
                        t2.col2 like '%' || t1.word || '%' or
                        t2.col3 like '%' || t1.word || '%'
                  );
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure that Hive supports non-equality conditions for the correlation.  If so, you may be out of luck with an easy solution.  The best you could do easily is:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t2.col1 = t1.word
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t2.col2 = t1.word
                 ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t2.col3 = t1.word
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query..

```
SELECT * FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT ID FROM table2 
        INNER JOIN table1 t1 
           ON Instr( (t2.column1 + t2.column2 + t2.column3),t1.word) > 0 
   WHERE t2.ID=tt2.ID)
```